# AWS CLI results in a text file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-ebs

I have 3000+ ebs volumes and I want to list them in aws cli.. however when I run the command

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes
```

the result ends up showing only one ebs volume and the terminal keeps saying "skipping".

I want to list all in a text file output maybe? or is there any other way to get all ebs volumes.

I need this to describe and filter out unused ebs volumes.. and then delete them!

Comment: Have you tried `aws ec2 describe-volumes > myfile.txt` or `aws ec2 describe-volumes | less`?

Comment: @Marcin yes thanks.. it worked!

Comment: Glad to hear that. If you don't mind I will provide an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The solution was to use either (to save output to file):

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes > myfile.txt
```

or to display it:

```
ec2 describe-volumes | less
```

Comment: I am puzzled, however - when I run `aws ec2 describe-volumes` I get **all** volumes. I don't have 3000+, but I have few hundred. Obviously, it's useless to have them just scroll - you have to redirect or pipe them, anyway. But I've never seen this *skipping* message on the terminal. But as long as OP is happy...

Comment: @Felix You could add `--filters` to limit the number, or just select info of interests (e.g. volume-id) using `--query`. But the form in the question and answer is the most comprehensive one.